# Toggle visibility of sibling element of $(this) element | No unique ID [jQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, toggle, selector

I need `div.edit-button` to toggle its sibling `div.additionalFieldForm`.

Note that there's more than one `div.edit-button` and `div.additionalFieldForm` on the page, but I would like to target the `div.additionalFieldForm` that is in the same "family" as the `div.edit-button` that was clicked.

```js
$(".edit-button").click(function () {

  // PROBLEMATIC SELECTOR BELOW:
  $(this).closest("div").prev().toggle();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="customFieldUl">
  <li class="customFieldLi">
    <label class="top_title">Additional Field</label>
    <div class="additionalFieldForm">Content</div>
    <div class="edit-button">Edit</div>
    <div class="remove-button">Remove</div>
  </li>
  <li class="customFieldLi">
    <label class="top_title">Additional Field</label>
    <div class="additionalFieldForm">Content</div>
    <div class="edit-button">Edit</div>
    <div class="remove-button">Remove</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I've tried other selectors but I couldn't specifically target just the `div.additionalFieldForm` sibling of the edit button being clicked.

**EDIT:** I realize that there must be an underlying problem because the selector works on jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/wf7jjoq7/), but not on my site, without any console errors.

Comment: Do you want to hide _Additional Field_ label?

Comment: No, I want to toggle visibility for `div.additionalFieldForm` everytime `div.edit-button` is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `siblings()`

```
$(".edit-button").click(function () {  
  $(this).siblings(".additionalFieldForm").toggle();
});
```

Comment: This didn't work either, I've tried multiple selectors, none seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```js
$(".edit-button").click(function () {

  // PROBLEMATIC SELECTOR BELOW:
  $(this).parent().find(".additionalFieldForm").first().toggle();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="customFieldUl">
  <li class="customFieldLi">
    <label class="top_title">Additional Field</label>
    <div class="additionalFieldForm"></div>
    <div class="edit-button">Edit</div>
    <div class="remove-button">Remove</div>
  </li>
  <li class="customFieldLi">
    <label class="top_title">Additional Field</label>
    <div class="additionalFieldForm"></div>
    <div class="edit-button">Edit</div>
    <div class="remove-button">Remove</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

`li` is the common parent. So,

```
$(".edit-button").click(function () {  
 $(this).closest("li").find(".additionalFieldForm").toggle();
});
```

Comment: This didn't work for me either, and no console errors too.